# SpannableString not working when using AppCompat theme

Tags: android, android-appcompat, spannablestring

I'm unable to get SpannableString to work when I set AppTheme to Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar.

I have a button and its text is set with a SpannableString. When I use Holo theme the text renders as expected, but when I switch to AppCompat theme the span effects seam to be ignored. How can I get the SpannableString to work  using the AppCompat theme?

[image]

styles.xml - when switching between those 2 themes I get very different results...

```
<resources>
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" />
  <!--<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />-->
</resources>
```

... for my button that uses SpannableString

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);

        String detail = "ABC";
        String caption = String.format("2 %s", detail);
        Spannable span = new SpannableString(caption);

        int detailIndex = caption.indexOf(detail);

        span.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, detailIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        span.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(0.5f), detailIndex, detailIndex+detail.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        button.setText(span);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `appcompat-v7` tweaks some widget to try to have them adhere more to Material Design aesthetics. It is possible that what they are doing has a bug, where it is converting the button caption into a regular string. If you can create a project that reproduces the problem, you might consider [filing an issue](http://b.android.com) about it.

Comment: I made a project that demonstrates this problem, it can be found here:
http://bit.ly/spannableString

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, it's not tied to `appcompat-v7`. If you remove the theme stuff entirely, and just use the default theme, on Android 5.0+ you will get `Theme.Material`, and the same effect can be seen there.

Part of the Material Design aesthetic is that button captions should be all caps, and however they implemented that is wiping out your spans. `appcompat-v7` works with your code on pre-5.0 devices, suggesting that their backported widget effects do not include the app-caps stuff, and that they are delegating to the standard widgets on 5.0+.

Adding `android:textAllCaps="false"` to your `Button` in the layout seems to clear up the problem.

Comment: adding android:textAllCaps="false" solves the issue. Awful framework.